Using an Excel Array Function from Python
What I am attempting to do is use Python to open up a new Excel workbook, write some array functions in the first row and save the file so that when I open the workbook, my data is there. I'm using =STOCKHISTORY() to be specific.
I stripped the code down a lot to make it easy to read and understand what I am doing. I'm going to use the index of the list to get the data for several stocks. Here's my simplified code:
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

stocks = ["AAPL"]

ws['A1'] = f"=STOCKHISTORY(\"{stocks[0]}\",\"1/1/20\",\"1/1/24\",2,1,1)"

wb.save("C:/Users/there/Desktop/TEST.xlsx")

The problem is that because this is an array function, Excel adds the @ operator and what you see in Excel is:

=@STOCKHISTORY("AAPL","1/1/20","1/1/24",2,1,1)

This will only show "Close" in the cell. It doesn't fill the column with any data at all.
I have found that =SUM(2,2) will work just fine, so it is just array functions.
***Just an added note: My goal is to fill the list stocks[] up with ticker symbols and use {stocks[0]} to fill each column with the stocks just by changing the index. I wanted to get one to work first.

would ws.append(["AAPL","1/1/20","1/1/24",sum([2,1,1])]) not work? or some version of that approach, I don't understand what is the question, or expected result..

@chickitychinachinesechicken The issue is when you do this with an array function, Excel doesn't use the string the way I wrote it; it adds an @ operator. I am entering '=STOCKHISTORY()' and when I open the workbook, it says, '=@STOCKHISTORY()' which is basically for forcing the function into one cell so you don't get the #SPILL error. I don't want it to add the @ operator.

Below code work for me:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.formula import ArrayFormula

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws["A1"] = ArrayFormula("A1:B6", '=_xlfn.STOCKHISTORY("AAPL", DATE(2024,6,10),DATE(2024,6,15))')

wb.save("test.xlsx")

Also, you can write =STOCKHISTORY("AAPL", DATE(2024,6,10),DATE(2024,6,15) in Excel, save the file, unzip the file, open /Book2/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml in the unzipped folder, you will see the formula is like this:

